# Foreach problem in laravel 10 - Need to only show a button relative to the event that i want to unsubscribe, but i get a button for each event

Tags: php, laravel

```
@if ($event->participants()->where('member_doner_id', auth()->user()->id)->first())
                            {{-- Usuário inscrito --}}
                            @foreach ($participants as $participant)
                                @if ($participant->member_doner_id == auth()->id())
                                    {{-- Este participante equivale ao usuário autenticado --}}
                                    <form action="{{ route('cancelarreg', ['participant' => $participant->id]) }}"
                                        method="POST"
                                        onsubmit="return confirm('Confirma que pretende cancelar inscrição?');">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <button class="oldest" style="float: right; width:100%;">Cancelar registo</button>
                                    </form>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
@endif
```

[image: Outcome]

[image: Database Structure]

I need to make it so it only shows a button regarding the event that the member_doner is assigned right now not all of them. The "member_doner_id" is part of a column of the "participants" table and "event_id" is also part of it.

Comment: You are _only_ checking if the `member_doner_id` is a match for the currently logged in user, but you are not checking if the record is also for the specific event you are currently creating the output for.